# Capture standard error of shell in makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem with the [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) in makefiles. Doing this:

```
var := $(shell some-command)
```

Allows me to capture the `stdout` of `some-command`.

Doing this:

```
var := $(shell some-command 2>&1)
```

Allows me to capture the `stdout` and the `stderr` of `some-command`.

How do I capture the `stderr` of the shell **itself**?

This makefile ilustrates the problem:

```
var1 := $(shell date 2>&1)
var2 := $(shell ls aaa 2>&1)
var3 := $(shell a-command-which-does-not-exist 2>&1)

show-me:
    @echo var1: \"$(var1)\"
    @echo var2: \"$(var2)\"
    @echo var3: \"$(var3)\"
```

It will produce:

```
/bin/sh: 1: a-command-which-does-not-exist: not found
var1: "So 6. Feb 00:37:05 CET 2022"
var2: "ls: cannot access aaa: No such file or directory"
var3: ""
```

I would like to capture `/bin/sh: 1: a-command-which-does-not-exist: not found` into `var3`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have to run it in a subshell:

```
var3 := $(shell $(SHELL) -c 'a-command-which-does-not-exist' 2>&1)
```

There's no other way unfortunately.

**ETA** OK, I figured it out.  The problem is that if the shell invoked by the `$(shell ...)` function exits with an error code of 127 (which is the shell's exit code for when it can't find a program to run), then GNU make will explicitly write its output to stderr rather than capture it (if you examine the `function.c:func_shell_base()` function you'll see this).

Any change to the shell that you invoke that ensures it doesn't exit with the 127 exit code will "fix" the problem:

```
$ cat Makefile
out := $(shell bad-program 2>&1 || exit 1)
$(info out = $out)

$ make
out = /bin/sh: 1: bad-program: not found
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

This might be a bug in GNU make.  I'll need to consider it.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know what version of make you have tested, but that does not work for me ... I have tried with both rediercting within the command and outside, same result: the `stderr` is not captured. The version you posted seems logically correct, but it does not work for me (`GNU Make 4.2.1`)

Comment: No my example is wrong.  The problem is it's not the command which is printing the error, so redirecting the output of the command won't help.  It's the shell printing the error, so you need to redirect the output of the shell: it should be `$(shell $(SHELL) -c bad-command 2>&1)`.  However, that doesn't work either and I'm not sure why... hmm...

Comment: My comment above is wrong :)